# Tableau Calculated Members, Result type: Set

Tags: mdx, tableau-api, olap

We're using Tableau with MSAS as datasource which requires us to use Calculated Members for specific measures etc.
In MDX you can create Set's and in Tableau's Calculated Members there is an option to choose Result type: Set.

However, I cannot find any documentation or practical examples how this is supposed to be used.
Has anyone tried it and how? Or does someone know how to use it and can share an example?
Is it the same as 'Create Set' in MDX?